# How do I move .bash_profile away from home

Tags: bash, bash-script

I need `.bash_profile` to be synched with Dropbox. The easiest way I can think of is to "redirect" the shell to search for `.bash_profile` in a custom folder.

So is that possible? Or are there any better solutions?

Comment: make symlink to file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Eddy_Em suggested, just link to it:

```
mv ~/.bash_profile ~/Dropbox/.bash_profile
ln -s ~/Dropbox/.bash_profile ~/
```